# How to run affected:lint to create checkstyle output

Tags: angular, lint, nrwl

I want to lint the projects in a nrwl nx workspace in the CI environment (Jenkins), generating checkstyle format output, ideally one checkstyle file per app/lib

Using `ng lint > output.file`, I get one file containing multiple xmls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><checkstyle version="4.3"></checkstyle>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><checkstyle version="4.3"><file name="../myworkspace/apps/asdf/myapp/src/app/app.component.ts"><error line="4" column="13" severity="error" message="The selector should be kebab-cased and include a dash (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-02)" source="failure.tslint.component-selector" /></file></checkstyle>
```

I would have to split up this file into multiple xml files to get valid files. Associating the file to an app/lib is difficult or impossible, because this can only be guessed from the path of a failing file.
In addition, I can not make use of the parallel feature of nrwl's nx affected:lint, increasing the lint speed a lot.

Using `yarn affected:lint ... --parallel > output.file` is even a little bit more difficult, because this file does not only contain the xml output from above, but some more informations from nx. Additionally (but I have not verified this), I had the impression that the output of parallel lints is mixed up.

Ideally, there was an option like `yarn affected:lint --reportToFile` that would produce one output file for each app and lib.